# How to perform JUnit testing on a class that uses interfaces not yet implemented as method parameters?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, interface

I can't figure out how to perform Junit testing on a class that uses an interface not yet implemented as method parameters. I don't know the implementation of the interface so i can't implement it.

For example I have this interface

```
public interface Command{
     public void execute();
     ....
}
```

and class that uses the interface as method parameters.

```
public class Manager{
    List<Command> listCommands = new List<Command>();

    public void storeCommand(Command command){
       listCommands.add(command);
    }
}
```

I read online one solution could be to use mockito to mock the implementation of the interfaces but i'm not sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, get yourself familiar with *mocking* concept in the *Unit Testing* context, as by asking this question, you demonstrate, that you are not.

Then choose some *mocking Framework* to stick with. [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) is a good, and probably the most popular one.

Finally, I will not (can not) teach you all the mocking features you can leverage with this framework, but this is one example of *how* you mock your type (be it an interface or class), and *how* you configure mocked instance to make it behave like you want it to behave:

```java
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

class YourTestFixture {

    @Test
    public void yourTest()  {
        //create mock
        Command commandMock = mock(Command.class);

        //configure execute() method's return value
        when(commandMock.execute()).thenReturn("your expected value");

        //your assertions..

    }
}
```

Now, every time you invoke `.execute()` on that particular instance (`commandMock`), it will consistently be returning `"your expected value"`.

Note, that you can make it throw an exception, or return `null`.. or just do anything you would like it to do, but the returning object/value must be of a type (or subtype) of whatever method declares to be returning.

Note, that in your example:

```java
public class Manager{
    List<Command> listCommands = new List<Command>();

    public void storeCommand(Command command) {
        listCommands.add(command);
    }
}
```

you are not even using any method invocation on the `command` parameter. So, you can simply mock your interface as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can mock an implementation of your interface using mockito like this :

```
Command mockedCommand = Mockito.mock(Command.class)
```

Then you can start mocking every method of your interface that will be used in your tests specifying what it shall return.